# how do you retrieve a auto generated id to delete data in firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to delete this data in the app but im not sure how to retrieve the uid of the one i need to delete:

so the first id is the current users id but how do i get the next unique id fo i can delete the records "test" and "Apple"

this is how i upload the data to the database:

```
var currentUid = mAuth.currentUser?.uid
val myRef = database.getReference("Users")
val myRefCategory = myRef.child(currentUid!!).child("Following")


  fun sendDataToDatabase(category: String) {

    myRefCategory.push().setValue(category)

  }
```

how do i get the "MLt1lk1wtyvqLtQGZRF" and "MLt1bpUmJmAkjz_7tGN"?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key you're looking for is in the [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) returned by [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()).

```
val ref = myRefCategory.push()
val key = ref.key  // this is your key
ref.setValue(...)
```

Comment: This code pushes a value and then immediately gets the auto-generated id of that pushed value afterwards, but how would you go about getting the auto-generated id and deleting a value which already exists and is created earlier in the app, in other words, getting the id when you actually want to delete it? Is there not a way of getting the id without saving it throughout from the creation of the object to the deletion of it?